# Calculated column - SharePoint 2007 what is wrong

Tags: sharepoint

I tried to create the formula for adding 2 years to some date. Can you please tell me what is wrong here?

```
=DATE(YEAR[Effective Date]+2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this formula:

```
=DATE(YEAR([Effective Date])+2;MONTH([Effective Date]);DAY([Effective Date]))
```

For more details see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: Not working - I have the error -> The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.  :(